# Does the IRS care that you get rewards when donating using a credit card? If so, how to account for that?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, charitable-contributions

It seems that the best way to donate regularly to a charity I wish to donate to and get a receipt for it is to use a credit card instead of a check. (Yes, I know this means that slightly less than I am actually charged will make it to the charity.)

It looks like I will be able to itemize my deductions this year, and will include my donations to this charity as part of those deductions (it qualifies). All my credit cards have rewards associated with them. Thus, by donating with a credit card, I'll get some rewards.

Does the IRS care about this, like they want me to account for how much rewards I received and decrease my reported donation by that amount? Have they provided any official guidance on this that someone can point me to? I tried searching for it online but couldn't find anything.

Comment: The points explicitly state it has no cash value. No cash value = 0. IRS can't tax that.

Comment: I've seen (don't have any sources ready to link) that rewards don't get reported as income because they are considered "discounts", effectively reducing the purchase price. Not sure whether that matters here, since the charity still receives the full amount (although they spend some of it on CC fees, unless you pay as part of the transaction)

Comment: The transaction cost is absorbed by the organization so your reported tax-deductible is actually what you were charged. The accounting side is a real nightmare on the NGO side though (I worked at one), and because NGOs don't have high volume, their processing fees are much higher than stores.

Honestly, I would just donate less and keep the money instead of trying to use CC for points when donating to NGOs.

Comment: @Nelson: On the other hand, charities keep pushing us to do monthly automatic small donations by credit card rather than yearly larger donation by check, for various reasons that make sense to their marketing and donor development departments. You can't do that and then complain about the card processing costs. (I have automated donations from my side of things, push vs. pull, and have had discussions with charities about whether they want that as one yearly check rather than 12 monthly checks. The response seems to mostly be "whatever keeps you supporting us.")

Comment: @keshlam There's a complex interaction of consistent donations via subscription vs the operation cost. For sure, the CC transactions are significantly more expensive to process than a bank transfer or even a cheque, but if the extra donation offsets the processing cost, then it is a net gain.

Of course, the CC companies take a cut out of that, so if you're more interested in giving the NGO more money, then setup scheduled bank transfers instead of using a CC subscription. You just need to recognize that processing costs are definitely non-trivial.

Comment: @Nelson "points explicitly state it has no cash value" That assumes the rewards are some sort of points. There are plenty of credit cards where the rewards are cash.

Comment: @keshlam a constant income stream is much easier to budget with than lump sum giving.

Comment: @blm I’ve never seen actual/direct cash back.  It’s always “exchange points for cash” when the bank deigns to offer cash back.

Comment: @RonJohn There are plenty of direct cash back cards, in fact most of mine are. For example, there’s https://www.bankofamerica.com/credit-cards/cash-back-credit-cards/ which has a bunch of them (and a couple that are points back).

Comment: @blm interesting.  Do they automatically/monthly send the “cash” to the checking account of your choice?

Comment: @RonJohn It depends on the credit card issuer, some let you do something with them automatically at the end of the month, others only let you distribute them manually. Distribution options also vary, but most include sending them to a bank account, or applying them as a statement credit (I think some even have getting a check as an option ‍♂️).

Comment: @blm and no points?  Just directly to cash?

Comment: @RonJohn Yep, all cash all the way. My available rewards are denominated in $, when I redeem them it's sending $ somewhere, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Credit card rewards have no relationship whatsoever with charitable giving.  Consider two cases:

- you use a credit card for charitable giving, and your rewards card gives you 1% cashback
- you use a credit card for random consumer goods, and your rewards card gives you 1% cashback

One doesn't get treated differently than the other. The fact that one is a charity has no bearing on the matter.

It isn't really relevant to the answer, but IRS will treat the cashback or rewards as a rebate/discount.  Really simpler that way - no 1099s.

And by the way, that charity-branded tote bag, mug or T-shirt, those are considered "inconsequential" for tax purposes.  The same for newsletters of non-commercial quality, or event tickets/admissions for *non-sporting* events. See IRS Publication 526.

Comment: It's a rebate, because it's preconditioned on spending (rewards not preconditioned on spending are treated as interest and reported in 1099-INT, but these are extremely rare nowadays).

Comment: Isn't the difference between the two cases that you are getting a deduction for donations to charity, while you can't write off "random consumer goods" for the most part?

Comment: @CraigW that doesn't affect the *rebate*.  The rebate is a thank-you for using the card as the payment method.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, because normally when you receive a benefit from a charitable organization that you donated to, the tax deductibility of your donation gets reduced by the amount of the benefit.

However, in the case of credit card rewards, you do not need to reduce your deduction because of a credit card rebate.

Your receipt from the charity should show the entire amount that you were charged on the credit card, and should not show the reduced amount that the charity received because of the payment processing fees.  If you received something of value for your donation, the receipt will show that as well.  You are able to deduct the amount of the donation on the charity's receipt, minus anything of value you received that is on the receipt.

Credit card rebates/rewards are not considered taxable income, and do not reduce any tax deductible purchase.